# How to display all the items in Session and their values in a repeater ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, session, repeater

i am a bit confused on how to display all the items in session in a repeater

Any suggestion??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`HttpSessionState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.aspx) implements `IEnumerable`, so you can bind directly to that.

```
// Code-behind
this.Repeater1.DataSource = Session;
this.Repeater1.DataBind();
```

The session enumerates its keys, not its values, so if you want to see both, do this in your .aspx template:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        Key: <%# Container.DataItem %>,
        Value: <%# Session[Container.DataItem.ToString()].ToString() %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```